# How to create maximum compatible zip files with Python3?

Tags: python, zip

I can create and read archive with the Python3 package `zipfile` without any problems. But I am not able to open that archives with other programms - not on Windows 10 (in-build extractor) nor GNU/Linux.

**My goal** is to create zip files with Python3 that can opened on nearly every machine and every zipper-programm.

The error messages using Windows10 archiver or XArchiver on XFCE are unspecific. But on the shell (Debian GNU/Linux 10) I can see this

```
$ unzip the_archive.zip
Archive:  the_archive.zip
   skipping: in_zip.txt              need PK compat. v6.3 (can do v4.6)
```

This is Python3 code to create such an archive

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import zipfile

# the file that will be zipped
with open('in_zip.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('foobar')

# create zip file
with zipfile.ZipFile('the_archive.zip', 'w',
                     compression=zipfile.ZIP_LZMA,
                     compresslevel=9) as zip_file:  # maximum
    zip_file.write('in_zip.txt')
```

Comment: For maximum compatibly, use `compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LZMA` compression method you are using is not widely supported. Below is taken from [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) man page.

> Note The ZIP file format specification has included support for bzip2
> compression since 2001, and for LZMA compression since 2006. However,
> some tools (including older Python releases) do not support these
> compression methods, and may either refuse to process the ZIP file
> altogether, or fail to extract individual files

For maximum interoperability, stick to `zipfile.ZIP_STORED` and `zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED`.

Next are the filenames you use in the zip file. Although `zipfile` can correctly store Unicode filenames in the zip archive, encoded as UTF8, you want to stay with 7-bit ASCII if interoperability is a key factor. Also, on Windows be aware of characters (and filenames) that are to be avoided. See [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) for more details.

If you have no choice and need to store filenames that are outside 7-bit ASCII, make sure they are properly encoded as UTF-8. The only portable character sets for zip files are 7-bit ASCII and UTF-8

The other feature to be careful with is `ZIP64` support. Most archivers do support it these days, but there are libraries that don't. You will only trigger it if you are dealing with are >4Gig, in which case you don't have much choice.